# Can I somehow wait for the specific script to be executed in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can I somehow wait for the specific script to be executed in Selenium?

Suppose that I have the following button:

```
<input name="some_name" value="" id="some_id" onkeyup="foo(this.value)" style="font:26px bold; cursor:default" type="text">
```

How can I wait for the "foo" function to be completed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this logic might work. You have to use JavaScriptExecutor of Selenium to execute the java scripts. The live event is hooked to the onkeyup event and its triggered after the main event.

PS: This is untested code.

> //set flag to false during page load
>
> $("#some_id").live("onkeyup", function(){   //set flag to true  })
>
> //check for flag if set using java script executor

Comment: Do you mean that I need to modify source code of the page?

Comment: No.. You can run custom javascript code from your selenium script. Check http://learn-selenium.com/webdriver/tutorials/executing-javascript